# How to how to convert username to discord ID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a simple questions about discord. I am trying to create an economy system, and it works well, but I want to customize it a bit. I am using this person's module: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

How do I convert a username to a discord ID. For example if I have a discord "command" to allow people to gift each other money, like: `james#0243` types `!give 100 bob#9413`.

How can I convert `bob#9413` to a discord id like `58492482649273613` because in my database, I have people's users stored as their ID rather than their  actual username as people can change their username.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) to get the `Member` object of the target, which will include their `id`.

```
from discord import Member
from dicord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def getids(ctx, member: Member):
    await ctx.send(f"Your id is {ctx.author.id}")
    await ctx.send(f"{member.mention}'s id is {member.id}")

bot.run("token")
```

Converters are pretty flexible, so you can give names, nicknames, ids, or mentions.

Comment: Sorry.  I a little new to python, so in this line `async def getids(ctx, member: Member):` I would replace `Member` with the username? Eg: `async def getids(ctx, member: bob#9413):`. I assume this will work even if the username is not in the server?

Comment: No. When you invoke the command in discord `!getids bob#9413`, the argument will get passed to a converter before it is passed to this coroutine.  By the time this code runs, `member` is a `Member` object.

Comment: Sorry, I've never used `@bot.command` only `@client.event`. Then using the `on_message` function. Is it possible for you to show me using the `client.event` and `on_message`. Keep the one you made first, but just another version of it on `client.event`. Sorry for being a pain.

Answer (score 0):

[`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) callback function is passed the `message`.

`message` is a [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message) instance. 
It has [`author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message.author) and 
[`mentions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message.author) attributes which could be instances of `discord.Member` or `discord.User` depending on whether the message is sent in a private channel.

The `discord.Member` class subclasses the [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.User) and the user `id` can be accessed there.

Comment: So that means the person has to type `!give 100 @bob#9413`?

Comment: That is correct. Is that a constraint you don't want? and would rather use the username without the `@` prefix?

Comment: Well I was wondering if there is a way to do it without the @ symbol. So a user would type `!give 100 bob#9413`

Comment: See Tristo's answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [get_member_named](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.get_member_named) to do something like

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def name_to_id(ctx, *, name):
  server = ctx.message.server
  user_id = server.get_member_named(name).id
```

> The name can have an optional discriminator argument, e.g. “Jake#0001” or “Jake” will both do the lookup. However the former will give a more precise result.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but this only matched the username if they are in the server? I am looking for any name. In the server or not in the server

Comment: You can only get information (users, roles etc.) from servers your bot is in when given the appropriate [permissions](https://discordapi.com/permissions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
prefix_choice = "!"
bot = commands.Bot(max_messages=10000, command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or(prefix_choice))

@bot.command()
async def membersLog(ctx):
    for i, member in enumerate(ctx.message.server.members):
        list_mem_num = (f'{i}')
        list_mem_id = (f'{member.id}')
        list_mem = (f'{member}')
        list_mem_name = (f'{member.name}')
        list_all = (f'Number: {list_mem_num} ID: {list_mem_id} Name: {list_mem} ({list_mem_name})\n')
        print(list_all)
```

You can use this to collect all memberinfo of the server where the call comes from. This is the code I use for this.